# Setup Azure MSSQL Database in Ejabberd server?

Tags: sql-server, windows, erlang, azure-sql-database, ejabberd

I'm developing chat application, I'm using ejabberd for my project. I installed ejabberd server(16.06) successfully and it performing good in auth method as internal. But it is not working when I'm changed auth method as sql. These are the things I'm changed in ejabberd.yml file

```
default_db: sql
auth_method: sql
## ODBC compatible or MSSQL server:
##
sql_type: mssql
sql_server: "Server=azure_server_name;DSN=DB_Name;UID=azure_DB_username;PWD=azure_DB_password"
sql_pool_size: 10
sql_keepalive_interval: 28800
mod_mam:
     iqdisc: one_queue
     db_type: sql
     default: always
```

I'm getting following error for while I'm register new user and admin login into web admin portal

```
ejabberd_auth:is_user_exists:316 The authentication module ejabberd_auth_sql returned an error
when checking user <<"newuser">> in server <<"localhost">>
Error message: {timeout,{p1_fsm,sync_send_event,[<0.390.0>,{sql_cmd,{sql_query,{sql_query,<<"Q9525209">>,#Fun<sql_queries.9.38301790>,#Fun<sql_queries.10.38301790>,#Fun<sql_queries.11.38301790>,{sql_queries,145}}},3534866},60000]}}
```

I'm used register command:

bin>ejabberdctl register "newuser" "localhost" "password"

Thanks in advance. Please add your ideas and suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does the user exist in the database? (I'm unfamiliar with ejabberd, but it sort of appears that the user doesn't exist.)

Comment: No user in database. I'm tried to add new user in database through the register command.

Comment: It also seems to be using your localhost DB instead of Azure SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

Again- I am no Ejabberd expert- I imagine someone might have more experience with this; However, it seems that you're confusing `Register` which I assume is an action to create a login on the Ejabberd platform with the login that is being used on the database. (Or I'm misinterpreting your comments. One of the two.)

You will need to use a username/password combination that exists on the Azure SQL Database in your connection string.

Additionally, you might try the following connection string : 
       `sql_server:"Server=tcp:azure_server_name.database.windows.net;DSN=DB_Name;UID=azure_DB_username;PWD=azure_DB_password"`